# Specify class variable in Python to be a numpy array of not yet known size

Tags: python-3.x, types

I have a class like

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.will_be_a_numpy_array = None

def compute():
    tmp = receive_data()
    self.will_be_a_numpy_array = np.zeros(len(tmp))
    # process each item in tmp, save result in corresponding element of self.will_be_a_numpy_array
```

Here `__init__` method is vague regarding the type of `self.will_be_a_numpy_array` variable. It is unclear to fellow developer or compiler what type of variable should be expected. I cannot initialize variable with `self.will_be_a_numpy_array = np.zeros(len(tmp))` because I haven't received data yet. What is the right way to articulate variable type in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strategy that [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable) uses for their estimators, namely, you create the attribute when you receive the data and you use a trailing underscore to warn that this is an attribute that is not created at initialisation:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, data):
        self.data_ = np.array(data)

    def is_processed(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'data_')
```